# Can I get working places for all users from organization using calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I wonder if I can get working places for all users from organization using calendar API. Coworkers from my organization uses google calendar to mark if they work from home or office. I attach screen to show what I am talking about.

[image: google calendar working places]

I've searched many endpoints from calendar API but did not find suitable one. Is it possible to get those information from API?

Answer (score 1):

It is not **yet** possible to retrieve those information from the API.

But Google already documented it ([tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/working-hours-and-location?hl=en), [API reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/user-availability/reference/rest?hl=en)) and it should come at some point in the (hopefully) near future.

Here is the related issue in their tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199918380