# Get work location from ALL users in my organization from their Google Calendar using GAS or Calendar API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Yes, this is a duplicate question of [Can I get working places for all users from organization using calendar API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74204778/can-i-get-working-places-for-all-users-from-organization-using-calendar-api) but that question is from 2022. Back then, Google did not have an API for work location. Now they do have an API for work location. Since that is an old question that nobody will see, I thought it best to post a new question.

Our company has a Google Workspace Enterprise account. I want to be able to see the work location for EVERYONE in my organization. Is this possible?

I know I can follow https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/working-hours-and-location to get work location for a specific user. But I want to do for ALL users.

Comment: According to the documentation that feature is available on primary calendars...so if you want to do it for all users, you'll probably have to leverage a service-account with domain-wide delegation of authority enabled and then impersonate each user with the service account to fetch work location data (per user) via the Calendar API. At least, that's how I'd tackle it, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm closing this to consolidate the answers. If the only reason for the new question is create current interest, you've done it and the closed question will continue to be present in the  first page and redirect to the original. Anyone willing to answer it can answer the original. OP can then upvote the answer there.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot If I remember right, OP's organization disallowed service accounts. Only other way, I can think of is using webapps to execute as others. But each of the users have to authorize individually.

Comment: Dag nab it. Thanks all!